# How to prevent duplicate HTML IDs?

Tags: html, xhtml

[The HTML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) doesn't allow duplicate IDs in the same document, but what are the tools web developers can use to enforce this requirement?

Some difficulties developers are faced with:

1. JavaScript can create IDs dynamically, so static checks don't always work.
2. Libraries being used may also create IDs in the document, and not all those IDs are named by developers.

Answer (score -1):

If your using an ide like dreamweaver there is orange dots on the same line as your id.

Best way to avoid having more than 1 id is to only use id's for structural stuff or something you know there is only going to be 1 of and classes for everything else.

Hope that helps